# Hosting a REST Composer Server Online?

Tags: node.js, rest, web-hosting, hyperledger-composer

Till now I was running the Composer REST Server (Blockchain) locally on the local host server. Now this server has got some post APIs configured which needs to be triggered by my main server already hosted on Heroku(Cloud Service).

So the flow of architecture is like my Android App calls Heroku Server which in turn has to call the Composer REST Server (which is running locally on my machine).

Hence I need to host the composer REST Server on a free tier cloud service. Although its a Node JS Server but it's package.json is weird and I am not able to find any resource which specifies how to take the Composer Online.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your underlying Fabric is running in Docker Containers?

Assuming that it is, you can run your Composer REST Server in a container too.  There is an example of this in the [composer documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html) for Multi-User mode which makes it look a little more complex, but the import piece is getting the Card in the container.  There is also a [Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) in the composer documentation again for multi user mode.